# Drawing route for two points on mapkit

Tags: iphone, drawing, mapkit, cllocation

I'm doing an iphone app concerning geolocation. Its working fine with mapkit and cllocation, now I want to draw a path for two points on the map, I dont need to be aware of streets or stuff like this, i only want to connect graphically an array of points that i already have.. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to extend onto user's comment, you can have overlays and annotations. check out [this](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136) for an example of polyline overlay.

basically you would leave your viewForAnnotations method alone and let it draw your placemarks. then you would have a viewForOverlay and let it draw any shapes like polylines onto your map. this is much cleaner and quicker than drawing a route in a custom annotation like we had to do prior to apples adding of MKOverlayViews

Answer (score 2):

this below link helps you :  https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions